# Flutter Client Grpc: Protoc-gen-dart: program not found

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, grpc, mobile-application

I am trying to make Flutter mobile client application in Dart. But I am getting error while install the protocol compiler plugin for Dart: protoc-gen-dart: program not found or is not executable. I install Flutter SDK, Dart SDK and Protocol buffer.

I am using grpc official site for integrating grpc. https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/quickstart/